# Javascript validation overwrites ASP.NET validators

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, overwrite

I have a problem that is making me crazy. On my page I have one **Javascript validation** and two **ASP.NET validators**. The validation outcome depends just on the result of the Javascript. That means if the Javascript returns **true** the ASP.NET validators are not checked.

The **Javascript** code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function Validate() {
        var ddlObj = document.getElementById('<%=ddStatus.ClientID%>');
        var txtObj = document.getElementById('<%=txtComment.ClientID%>');
        if (ddlObj.selectedIndex != 0) {
            if (txtObj.value == "") {
                alert("Any change of Status requires a comment!");
                txtObj.focus();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Instead the two **ASP.NET validators** are:

```
<td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSerialNr" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="txtSerialNr" ErrorMessage="***" />
                        </td>

<td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtProdName" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfv1" ControlToValidate="txtProdName" ErrorMessage="***"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
```

Anybody might help? Thanks

UPDATE:

I call the Javascript from a button:

```
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" Text="Save New Product" 
style="cursor:hand" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

But I register the attribute from the **code-behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnSubmit.Attributes.Add("OnClientClick", "return Validate()");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fire the client side validation from within the `Validate()` function:

```
validate = function(){
    bool isValid = Page_ClientValidate(""); //triggers validation
    if (isValid){
        var ddlObj = document.getElementById("<%=ddStatus.ClientID%>"); 
        var txtObj = document.getElementById("<%=txtComment.ClientID%>"); 
        if (ddlObj.selectedIndex != 0) { 
            if (txtObj.value == "") { 
                alert("Any change of Status requires a comment!"); 
                txtObj.focus(); 
                isValid = false; 
            } 
        } 
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

Markup:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClientClick="return validate();" ... />
```

Comment: You solution seemed perfect but it does not work. I tried many different combinations without success. How can I check whether the Page_ClientValidate returns true if I actually fill in both textboxes managed by the ASP.NET validators? Thanks

Comment: In what sequence do you want the validation to execute?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a casing issue. My function is called `validated` whereas yours is `Validate`. JavaScript is very picking about casing.

Comment: yes I didn't copy/paste. I tried your code as well as mine by writing 'function Validate()'. Getting crazy

Comment: What's happening? Are you making it into the function? I would suggest adding alerts throughout the function to make sure that you're getting through all of the logic. How should validation be working? Should it validate the required fields, and then run your custom logic?

Comment: I found the problem. It really made me crazy. Your script is perfect thanks. The problem was the OnClientClick. It should've been OnClick. I don't know the reason, probably the Onclick has higher priority than OnClientClick even though it seems really stupid!

Answer (score 1):

OK, there's a couple of things wrong here.

If you are concerned enough to do validation, you must ALWAYS do server-side validation in addition to client-side. Client-side validation is very user-friendly and fast to respond, but it can be bypassed simply by setting JavaScript to 'off'!

I don't see where you've told your controls which JavaScript function to call when they validate? You use `RequiredFieldValidators` which don't require an external function - but then attempt custom validation using your `Validate()` function.

If you *do* end up using a `CustomValidator`, then you'll need to change the 'signature' of your function. It needs to be of the form

```
   function validateIt(sender, args){
            var testResult = //your validation test here
            args.IsValid = testResult;
        }
```

Comment: thanks fro your answer. I know that it should be accompanied by server side validation but that one is much easier to perform. I prefer to have a client side validation working and than implement the server side one. About your other concern, see my update

Comment: What you need to be doing is using a `CustomValidator` and performing all the validation in that. No point having a `RequiredFieldValidator` AND custom validation.